# Keydown event how to listen with hotkey

Tags: c#, wpf

I have registed ctrl+` as a hotkey,and I want to display a window when I press the hotkey and not release the leftctrl key and toggle ` key to do something else just like alt+tab switch the application.Here is the code.

```
private void ListOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SystemKey==Key.LeftCtrl && e.Key == Key.Oem3)
    {
        m_host.SelectNext();
    }
}
```

But I found this way only fired one key.So what's the right way to fire the key event?

And here is the debug information.
[debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Wpe.png)

Comment: When you say 'Hotkey' do you mean that it should also get triggered when you are not currently active in your windows e.g. a 'Global Hotkey'?

Comment: Yes,the hotkey is a global hotkey.It displays and activates a window.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your keydown event to detect the modifier this way

```
private void ListOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.Oem3)
    {
        m_host.SelectNext();
        e.Handled = true;
    }      
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it works,but I want to know how to do it with key event.

Comment: The keyboard.Modifiers is none too.

Comment: Are you sure because when i was debugging i got the modifier as Control?

Comment: Yep,because the ctrl key is always pressing after the hotkey has been triggered,I guess it has something to do with it.

Comment: How is that possible if you press both of them together

Answer (score -1):

Because onKeyDown event works for ONE key only, in order to use two keys at same time you need little improvise:

```
bool firstkeyisOn = false;
private void ListOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SystemKey==Key.LeftCtrl/*Or other key by choice*/)
    {
        firstkeyisOn = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if(firstkeyisOn  && (e.Key == Key.Oem3/*Or other key by choice*/))
    {
        m_host.SelectNext();
    }
}

private void ListOnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SystemKey==Key.LeftCtrl/*Key must be same as holding one*/)
    {
        firstkeyisOn = false;
    }
    //or
    //firstkeyisOn = false;
}
```

To cancel hotkey mode you just add firstkeyisOn = false under OnKeyUp event and you good to go.

Comment: You can see that the e.SystemKey is None.

Comment: But I doubt if checking for systemkey none it ever trigger event, because no key was clicked?

Comment: One key is not release,but the key status should be keydown?

Comment: look for my updated code, just checked on test app and it works great

Comment: This is bad technique. Ctrl is a modifier key. https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/modifiers/

Comment: He free to change key he wants, this technique is good enough, key choices are bad.

Comment: I think the choice of keys is also unwise but that's beside the point. Flagging is unnecessary and bad technique. It's made your code unnecessarilly brittle and introduced a bug. That code isn't going to work reliably. You don't even switch your flag back.

Comment: my code is ON/OFF logic you hold key you get function working, you release key and holding mechanism is not working, I wonder what bug could it be? :D

Comment: I put comment on bottom of my code to warn that needs event to cancel hotkey mode, seems nobody reads it :D

Comment: It's not work,e.SystemKey and Keyboard.Modifiers are both none.

Comment: did event is even called for you, i believe that you have event defined in code but in xaml its not assigned.